# Find the latest file using python, regex and glob

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching, glob

I have a more the 500 files in a directory and its updates daily. The file looks like following.

```
CC-exoc0512.2015.01.01_20150120_0551.csv
CC-pxoc0312.2015.01.01_20150120_0551.csv
CC-copy_exoc0412.2015.01.01_20150120_0551.csv
CC-exoc0302.2015.01.01_20150120_0551.csv
CC-pxoc0402.2015.01.01_20150120_0551.csv
CC-2015.01.01_exoc0502_20150120_0551.csv
```

I want to find the latest file which contains `exoc`. Such as if file name contains `exoc` return the latest file.

I was using `iglob`, which the filename is just first few letters.

```
newest = max(glob.iglob(r'c:\user\loading\CC-StightFileName*'), key=os.path.getctime)

print('newest file is : ' + newest)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to simply do:

```
c:\path\to\*exoc*
```

Using your current code would find the latest of any filename containing `exoc`.

If you wanted more fine-grained control you could do:

```
c:\path\to\CC-*exoc*
```

Would only find the latest file starting with `CC-` containing `exoc` in the filename.